# Class String and nested vector C++

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

I'm having difficulties to debug the following code. However, the output is kind of strange.

```
Compilation successful
Running tests.....

empty vector passed
small sorted failed
input:
abc def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz
expected output:
abc def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz
actual output:
abc def�� ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz� 
--------------------------------------------------------------
small decreasing failed
input:
wxyz tuv pqrs mno jkl ghi def abc
expected output:
abc def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz
actual output:
abc�� def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz 
--------------------------------------------------------------
small randomised failed
input:
pqrs wxyz jkl tuv abc mno def ghi
expected output:
abc def ghi jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz
actual output:
abc def ghi�� jkl mno pqrs tuv wxyz 
--------------------------------------------------------------
large failed
input:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate       
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
mollit anim id est laborum.
expected output:
Duis Excepteur Lorem Ut ad adipiscing aliqua. aliquip amet, anim aute 
cillum commodo consectetur consequat. culpa cupidatat deserunt do dolor 
dolor dolore dolore ea eiusmod elit, enim esse est et eu ex 
exercitation fugiat id in in in incididunt ipsum irure labore laboris 
laborum. magna minim mollit nisi non nostrud nulla occaecat officia 
pariatur. proident, qui quis reprehenderit sed sint sit sunt tempor 
ullamco ut ut velit veniam, voluptate
actual output:
Duis� Excepteur���� Lorem Ut��� ad��� adipiscing aliqua. aliquip amet, 
anim� aute� cillum commodo consectetur�� consequat.��� culpa 
cupidatat���� deserunt����� do��� dolor dolore dolore dolor ea��� 
eiusmod elit, enim� esse� est�� et��� eu��� ex��� exercitation� fugiat 
id��� in��� in��� in��� incididunt��� ipsum irure labore laboris 
laborum.����� magna minim mollit nisi� non�� nostrud nulla 
occaecat����� officia pariatur.���� proident,���� qui�� quis� 
reprehenderit sed�� sint� sit sunt� tempor ullamco ut��� ut velit 
veniam, voluptate���� 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't now why the program makes such a strange output.
As followed I include the code written.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Vector
{
  public:
    // member types
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator = T*;
    using const_iterator = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;

    // constructors
    Vector () : first {nullptr}, last {nullptr}, limit {nullptr} {}

    Vector (std::size_t size) : Vector (size, size) {}

    Vector (const Vector& vector) : Vector (vector.last - vector.first)
    {
        std::copy (vector.first, vector.last, first);
    }

    Vector (Vector&& vector) : Vector ()
    {
        swap (vector);
    }

    // deconstructor
    ~Vector ()
    {
        delete [] first;
    }

    // assignment
    Vector& operator = (const Vector& vector)
    {
        Vector copy {vector};
        swap (copy);
        return *this;
    }

    Vector& operator = (Vector&& vector)
    {
        swap (vector);
        return *this;
    }

    // iterators
    iterator begin ()
    {
      return first;
    }

    iterator end ()
    {
      return last;
    }

    const_iterator begin () const
    {
      return first;
    }

    const_iterator end () const
    {
     return last;
    }

    std::size_t size () const
    {
     return last - first;
    }

    // element access
    reference operator [] (std::size_t index)
    {
     return first[index];
    }

    const_reference operator [] (std::size_t index) const
    {
     return first[index];
    }

    // modifiers
    void swap (Vector& vector)
    {
        std::swap (first, vector.first);
        std::swap (last, vector.last);
        std::swap (limit, vector.limit);
    }

    void push_back (const value_type& value)
    {
        if (last == limit)
        {
            std::size_t size = last - first;
            Vector vector {size, size * 2 + 1};
            std::move (first, last, vector.first);
            swap (vector);
        }

        *last = value;
        ++last;
    }

    void pop_back (const value_type& value)
    {
        std::size_t size = last - first;
        std::size_t cap = limit - last;

      if (cap > 2 && size <= cap / 4)
        {
            Vector vector {size, size * 2 + 1};
            std::move (first, last, vector.first);
            swap (vector);
        }

    }

    void clear ()
    {
        last = first;
    }

  private:
    Vector (std::size_t size, std::size_t capacity) : first {new value_type[capacity]}, last {first + size}, limit {first + capacity} {}

    iterator first;
    iterator last;
    iterator limit;
};

template<typename T>
Vector<T> read ()
{
    Vector<T> vector;
    for (T value; std::cin >> value;) vector.push_back (value);
    return vector;
}

template<typename T>
void sort (T* begin, T* end)
{
  std::size_t size = end - begin;
    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != size; ++index)
    {
        auto minimum = index;
        for (auto comparand = minimum; comparand != size; ++comparand)
            if (*(begin + comparand) < *(begin + minimum))
              minimum = comparand;
        if (minimum != index)
          std::swap (*(begin + minimum), *(begin + index));
    }
}

template<typename T>
void write (T* begin, T* end)
{
   std::size_t size = end - begin;
    for (std::size_t index = 0; index != size; ++index)
        std::cout << *(begin + index) << ' ';
}

class String
{
    public:
    // constructors
    String () {}

    // iterators
    char* begin ()
    {
      return string.begin();
    }

    char* end ()
    {
      return string.end();
    }

    const char* begin () const
    {
      return string.begin();
    }

    const char* end () const
    {
        return string.end();
    }

    // modifiers
    void clear ()
    {
      string.clear();
    }

    String& operator += (char character)
    {
            string.push_back(character);
    }

  private:
  Vector<char> string;
  std::size_t size;
};

bool operator < (const String& a, const String& b)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const String& string)
{
  os << string.begin();
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, String& string)
{
    string.clear (); 
    while (is.good () && std::isspace (is.peek ())) is.ignore ();
    while (is.good () && std::isgraph (is.peek ())) string += is.get ();
    if (string.begin () == string.end ()) is.setstate (is.failbit);
    return is;
}


int main ()
{
    auto vector = read<String> ();
    sort (vector.begin (), vector.end ());
    write (vector.begin (), vector.end ());
}
```

The program should take from the input some strings, sort them lexicographical and then print. However, I think my mistake is the operator overloading function for the string. But don't know how to improve the function.

Thanks for any help :)

---

**-EDIT-**

I found the error sitting in the

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const String& string)
```

The correct function would be

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const String& string)
{
  for(auto x : string)
  os << x;
  return os;
}
```

Thanks to all the help given. :)

Comment: check your `end()` method...

Comment: What do you mean by that? @user463035818

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause for the observed output, but it definitely causes undefined behaviour when the method is called. Your `Vector::end()` is this:

```
const_iterator end () const {  
    last; 
}
```

This method is not returning anything.

Note that a decent compiler should warn you about the statment having no effect.

Comment: Oh what a bad mistake. So I changed it to `return last;` but this doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: @ArisMartinAccola as mentioned by others, you do not provide enough information to reproduce the problem (and at the same time it is a bit too much code). Please use a debugger to narrow down the problem and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I already run a debugger and can't find the fault. For this reason I asked for help her. I already mentioned in my description that I think the problem is in the outstream function. I enclosed the hole code because it can also be that in the other parts is an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no code in your question to reproduce the problem you observe.

Couple of issues I spotted:

1. The copy constructor allocates memory and then copies elements. If copying throws the destructor never runs and it leaks memory.
2. The non-public allocating constructor uses `new` which invokes elements' default constructors. That is a wasted effort if the next thing you do is overwriting the lements in the copy constructor.

Comment: @ArisMartinAccola Use `unique_ptr` for `first` or your own RAII wrapper.

Comment: Could you please write me the code snippet you mean because I don’t exactly understand it. I’m quite new to programming. Many thanks.

Comment: @ArisMartinAccola `std::unique_ptr<iterator> first;`.

Comment: So far I can follow you but I don’t understand where I need to chance this. Do you mean it instead of iterator first or somewhere else?

Comment: @ArisMartinAccola Change the type of `Vector::first` from `iterator` to `std::unique_ptr<iterator>`.

Comment: I changed it but it doesn't compile anymore. `/home/cxrun/projectfiles/main.cpp:135:9: error: 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
    std::unique_ptr<iterator> first;
         ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.`

Comment: @ArisMartinAccola One day you will make it compile.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

I close the question because I found the answer. Thanks to anybody who helped me.